# Swing: creating a checkbox or check symbol in menuItem of jMenu

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jmenu, jmenubar

I want to create a checkbox or check symbol in front of menuItem in a `JMenu`. 
For example, when we open a Notepad file and click on Format menu there is a checkbox in front of Word Wrap menuItem of the Format menu.

Answer (score 37):

Use a [`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html) for check boxes in a menu.